# How to draw a line with a pattern

Tags: fabricjs

Is there a way to draw a simple line using a pattern?

I have used the `PatternBrush` with an image source, but it acts more like the object's name implies, a brush.  This doesn't allow it to just follow the cursor in `FreeDrawMode` creating a pattern, in this case a series of dashes with some text in-between.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebpo8ccg/1/).  To understand the issue, try drawing a straight line and curving it in a direction.  It is more of a "scratch" to reveal process.

Comment: what browser are you using? Seems ok with chrome?

Comment: @jbutler483 The brush works fine, but the problem is I want it to be a repeatable line vs it filling an area.  If you moved the cursor up, the pattern would start drawing in a diagonal line, but it actually "paints" the pattern in a parallel fashion.